# How to handle duplicate posts requests in web api

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a scenario where User enters all his details in a Form and clicks Submit (Post request) in Asp.Net Web api. What if the user clicks the Post button twice. How do I handle the request.

Any one please answer this question.

Comment: disable the button after the user clicks it

Comment: @sme That's not possible if you are shipping api only.

Comment: try to use token based API call. Use oauth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something you should'nt cocern about if you use view models But since this is api things should are little bit complicated.

You can argue @sm that disable submit button when the user submit a request, but if you are shipping a pure api and you are not responsible for the consumer. Then it's out of the question

Things that we do in our office are the ff.

1. Tokenized Handshake.
   Each POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE Request (Almost Any non GET Request) Should get a token from the server before accessing the API endpoint. In this part you can check how many times the user has requested a token to use. This is complicated but you can track the user's activity. You can also set threshold of request and ban the user if it exceeds the reasonable request a human can send without intent of breaking your api.
2. Use a secret special Header Attribute.
   If you are shipping api that is for private commercial use, Use a secret headers key and give the cred to trusted party that will consume your api.
3. Different Model for GET and POST. And for god's USE DTO instead of using the POCO class directly at your action method
4. I don't quite familiar but our DEVOps ensure that if we are shipping a public api. There should be a DDOS Filtering configuration made in your IIS prod environment.

Answer (score 4):

I completely disagree with @keysl, if you're creating an API you should probably be thinking of making it RESTFul and rest services should be idempotent, [take a read of this article](https://restfulapi.net/idempotent-rest-apis/) perhaps:

"In the context of REST APIs, when making multiple identical requests has the same effect as making a single request"

**UPDATE**

The effect POST has is the same, a new record is created! If there is a uniqueness constraint then you should return the correct status code, for instance 400. In the API's I work on we would return 400 and a JSON object with information of why validation/verification failed.

If the API is public then this is all you can do, you can't be held responsible for what people hit your API with. I work on a public API with well over a thousand endpoints and we do not worry about the user submitting data twice by accident, we just validate for uniqueness.

If this question is asking about a private endpoint that back a website then I totally agree with the disabling of the submit button, but you still should be using validation in the back end API and the front end should handle the returning of 400 gracefully.

While what @keysl is saying are all valid things (except DTOs are POCOs, thats just weird thing to say) I think points 1, 2 and 4 don't relate to the question at all and view models have nothing to do with a user clicking the button twice!

Comment: The Post method is not idempotent.

Comment: In the article that you linked and quoted: "Generally – not necessarily – POST APIs are used to create a new resource on server. So when you invoke the same POST request N times, you will have N new resources on the server. So, POST is not idempotent." And if you think about this further, if a resource has a uniqueness constraint (eg. a tag system like the tags on SO with the rule that a tag name must be system unique), how can the second request not violate this condition? the second should fail

Comment: I guess it depends on what you're saying should be idempotent, is the effect that a new record is created or that the same record is created. I sometimes write systems where the frontend can pass in an ID (GUID) to the POST method then if you hit it many times the outcome is the same, but the after the first time I would be updating or doing nothing rather than creating. If a resource has a uniqueness constraint that is violated just return 400 saying so, no?